# Are unregistered users more likely to post edits as "answers"?

Tags: discussion, answers

In [Nil class error for array sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661911/nil-class-error-for-array-sorting/5672752#5672752) , there's a !answer by the same person with a different user ID, saying

> i know i am duffer. My editing is block. so other way to post my problem

I've flagged the "answer", but I'm wondering: are unregistered users more likely to post edits as "answers" than registered users?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as:

- new users are more likely to get things wrong
- and unregistered users are more likely to be new user

**However, so what?**